# How to add a WFS layer to an OSM base layer from GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, wfs

I'm sorry if I'm repeating what has been asked several times!

I'm a novice in OpenLayers and JavaScript, please can some one tell me where i am making a mistake, below is the code which I used to add my base map and the vector layer, I am using OpenLayers version 2.13.1, and I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined
```

with:

```
var WGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
```

and with:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
```

Please can someone help me out on this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<!-- OpenLayers core js -->
    <script type='text/javascript'src="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jslib/OpenLayers-2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <!-- OpenStreetMap base layer js -->
    <script type='text/javascript'src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <script type='text/javascript'src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function init() {
        //set up projections

        // World Geodetic System 1984 projection
        var WGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

        // WGS84 Google Mercator projection
        var WGS84_google_mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

        //Initialize the map
        //creates a new openlayers map in the <div> html element id map
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
            controls:[
                //allows the user pan ability
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                //displays the pan/zoom tools
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                //displays a layer switcher
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                //displays the mouse position's coordinates in a <div> html element with
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                    div:document.getElementById("coordinates")
                })
            ],
                projection: WGS84_google_mercator,
                displayProjection: WGS84
        } );

        //base layers
        var openstreetmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var google_maps = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Maps", {
                numZoomLevels: 20
            }
        );
        var google_satellite = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Satellite", {
                type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                numZoomLevels: 20
            }
        );

        //wfs overlay
        var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("province2010", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            projection: WGS84,
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: "1.1.0",
                url: "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/chinavector1/wfs",
                featureNS :  "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/chinavector1/wfs",
                featureType: "province2010",
            })
        });

        map.addLayers([openstreetmap, google_maps, google_satellite, wfs_layer]);

        // map extent
        var mapextent = new OpenLayers.Bounds([74, 54, 135, 17]).transform(WGS84, map.getProjectionObject());
        map.zoomToExtent(mapextent);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
    <div id="coordinates"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. You need to add more information to your question, like the version of OpenLayers you are using, what actual error you are getting. This is needed so that experienced users can give you the answer you need.

Comment: You also should Search GIS@SE using the Search box at the top right of the Page to see if you question has already been answered to save you question being marked as a duplicate, or add unique information that has not been answered already. Cheers

Comment: @MarkC i've made some modifications in the question, hope its clear now. Thanks for your advice